# How to get hidden fields from AWS Resource in Cloud Custodian policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudcustodian

I am using cloud custodian policy to filter AWS ECS resources with Container Insights enabled. I have run the policy without `filters`, but I am unable to see the `containerInsights` field in the `resources.json` file

```
policies:
  - name: my-policy
    resource: aws.ecs
```

I tried to investigate this by running aws cli command `aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster my-cluster`, but output json of this shows `"settings": []`. However there is a flag `--include SETTINGS` which needs to be passed in order for the settings to show. So now when I run the command `aws ecs describe-clusters --include SETTINGS --cluster my-cluster`, it shows the `containerInsights` field

```
{
    "clusters": [
        {
            
            "clusterName": "my-cluster",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            ...
            "settings": [
                {
                    "name": "containerInsights",
                    "value": "enabled"
                }
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    "failures": []
}
```

I want to include this filter in my cloud custodian policy but somehow I am unable to get the *hidden* `settings` field, I have tried the following in my policy but it hasn't worked out yet and gives `count: 0`, I have clusters with container insights enabled and disabled as well.

```
policies:
  - name: my-policy
    resource: aws.ecs
    filters:
      # - "settings.name.containerInsights": enabled
      - type: value
        key: "settings[].name.containerInsights"
        op: eq
        value: enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your value filter JMESPath should be similar to the below:

```
policies:
  - name: my-policy
    resource: aws.ecs
    filters:
      # - "settings.name.containerInsights": enabled
      - type: value
        key: "settings[].containerInsights"
        op: eq
        value: enabled
```

I would experiment personally and it is usually a combination of community docs and AWS API references that gets me to the bottom of it in general.

Also if you enable `--verbose` on run, you could get valuable details to, if any.